# Git Rebase Won't Let Me Type

Tags: cmd.exe, git

I'm trying to do a git rebase on the Windows CMD to change a commit message (I've also tried the git bash but the exact same problem occurs there). When I do the rebase via

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

I've seen that I should change `pick` to `reword` to change an old commit message, but as I try to type, about 90% of my keystrokes do something beyond my understanding. Backspace usually works like left arrow, typing will delete words but doesn't type anything, some characters make my caret jump. I'm assuming that these are all keyboard shortcuts that people would want, but I just want to type. How can I simply type when I've started a rebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have *vim* as your default text editor. It's very powerful, but its user interface is *modal*. Basically all software released for the last 2 decades is modeless, so you may not be used to it. Here's a quick *vim* howto:

- Press <kbd>I</kbd> to enter edit mode - you can navigate with arrow keys, typing works as expected
- When you're done, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit edit mode
- Once out of edit mode, type `:wq`<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save changes and exit *vim*
- To discard changes, type `:q!` <kbd>Enter</kbd> (this will *not* cancel the rebase - it will carry on without your
  changes; to cancel you have to empty the rebase plan)
- To delete a whole line quickly, make sure you are not in edit mode and press <kbd>D</kbd> twice

If that sounds crazy to you, you're not alone. You can use a different editor by changing the `EDITOR` variable, setting `VISUAL` variable or [configuring `core.editor`](https://git-scm.com/book/pl/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Comment: I so hate VI. In college we had to use ksh over ssh, and they had configured it so that the arrow keys wouldn't work, so to navigate a command string we had to use VI navigation key commands. awful.